# yii2 model validating but form not storing data in database

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii2

When I validate my form with `$model->validate()` the validation works perfect but when all data is filled in form still its not saving data to a database and even it is not redirecting. tell me solution.

Below is my code

Controller's code of `actionCreate()`:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new ClientUsers();

    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        // && $model->validate()
        //get file instance
        $imageName = $model->first_name . '_' . Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
        if ($model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file'))
        {
            $model->profile_pic = '../../user_uploads/' . $imageName . '.' . $model->file->extension;
            $model->file->saveAs('../../user_uploads/' . $imageName . '.' . $model->file->extension);
        }
        $model->created_date = date('d-m-y h:m:s');
        $model->updated_date = date('d-m-y h:m:s');
        $model->updated_by = Yii::$app->user->identity->username;
        $model->password_hash = $model->setPassword($model->password_hash);
        $model->auth_key = $model->generateAuthKey();
        //$model->validate();
        $model->save();

        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);


    }   

    else {

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Model's code:

```
<?php
namespace backend\models;

use Yii;

use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "client_users".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $first_name
 * @property string $last_name
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $mobile
 * @property integer $gender
 * @property string $profile_pic
 * @property string $address
 * @property integer $city
 * @property integer $state
 * @property integer $country
 * @property integer $pincode
 * @property string $status

 * @property string $created_date
 * @property string $updated_by
 * @property string $updated_date
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $auth_key
 * @property string $password_hash
 * @property string $password_reset_token
 */
class ClientUsers extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public $file;
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'client_users';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'mobile', 'gender',/* 'profile_pic', */'address', 'city', 'state', 'country', 'pincode', 'created_date',/* 'updated_by', 'updated_date',*/ 'username', 'auth_key', 'password_hash',/* 'password_reset_token'*/], 'required'],
            [['gender', 'city', 'state', 'country', 'pincode'], 'integer'],
            [['gender', 'city', 'state', 'country', 'pincode'], 'required'],
            [['first_name', 'last_name', 'email',  'created_date', 'updated_by', 'updated_date'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['mobile'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
            [['address','profile_pic'], 'string', 'max' => 300],
            [['status'], 'string', 'max' => 10],
            [['status'],'required'],
            [['email'],'email'],
            [['username', 'password_hash', 'password_reset_token'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['auth_key'], 'string', 'max' => 32],
            [['file'],'safe'],
            [['file'],'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true],
            ['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 'message' => 'This email address has already been taken.'],
            ['username', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 'message' => 'This username has already been taken.'],

        ];
    }


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'first_name' => 'First Name',
            'last_name' => 'Last Name',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'mobile' => 'Mobile',
            'gender' => 'Gender',
            'profile_pic' => 'Profile Pic',
            'address' => 'Address',
            'city' => 'City',
            'state' => 'State',
            'country' => 'Country',
            'pincode' => 'Pincode',
            'status' => 'Status',

            'created_date' => 'Created Date',
            'updated_by' => 'Updated By',
            'updated_date' => 'Updated Date',
            'username' => 'Username',
            'auth_key' => 'Auth Key',
            'password_hash' => 'Password',
            'password_reset_token' => 'Password Reset Token',
            'file' => 'Profile Picture',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Generates password hash from password and sets it to the model
     *
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
        return "$this->password_hash";
    }

    /**
     * Generates "remember me" authentication key
     */
    public function generateAuthKey()
    {
        $this->auth_key = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
        return "$this->auth_key";
    }
}
```

View's code:

```
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\arrayHelper;
use backend\models\CityMaster;
use backend\models\StateMaster;
use backend\models\CountryMaster;
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model backend\models\ClientUsers */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="client-users-form">
    <div class="row">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'first_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'last_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'mobile')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">

    <?= $form->field($model, 'gender')->radioList(array('1'=>'Male','0'=>'Female')); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">

    <?=
   $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput(); 
    ?>

    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">

    <?= $form->field($model, 'address')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">

    <?= $form->field($model, 'country')->dropDownList(
            arrayHelper::map(countrymaster::find()->all(),'id','country_name'),[
            'prompt'=>'Select Country',
            'onchange'=>'
                    $.post("index.php?r=state/lists&id='.'"+$(this).val(), function(data){
                        $("select#clientusers-state").html(data);
                        });'
            ]
    )->label('Country'); ?>
    </div>
    </div>
     <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'state')->dropDownList(
            arrayHelper::map(statemaster::find()->all(),'id','state_name'),['prompt'=>'Select State Name']
    )->label('State'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">

    <?php
    //$form->field($model, 'city')->textInput() 
    ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'city')->dropDownList(
            arrayHelper::map(citymaster::find()->all(),'id','name'),[
            'prompt'=>'Select City',

            ]
    )->label('City'); ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'pincode')->textInput() ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
   <?= $form->field($model, 'status')->dropDownList(array('10'=>'Active','0'=>'Inactive')); ?>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">  

    <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">


    <?= $form->field($model, 'password_hash')->passwordInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
</div>
</div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Check modal save status using `var_dump($model->save())`.

Comment: try printing the error by using $model->getErrors()

Comment: both solutions are not working guys. it is still not showing any errors. only form remains on page after submitting data.

Comment: @kushalshah Dump just the model `var_dump($model)`.  If you're using the php's built in web server you can see the dump on the server console (terminal where php server is running) else check the web server's log file.  I have often found that the rules have a role to play in the way POST variables get loaded into the model `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())`.  Yii by default ignores the properties (attributes) that are not defined in the rule.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you don't check the model validate

```
 if($model->validate()) {
     // your code for validate true
 }
```

However `validate()` doesn't show you the error. It justs check the validation rules and answers  true or false.

For testing you can try:

```
$model->save(false);
```

In this way, the model is saved without checking the validation. 
If in this way, the model is saved, this mean you have some validation rules not correct or some data not respecting them.

Answer (score 1):

You can simple check whether the model is saved. If yes then only redirect otherwise print the error. Please do the following and check whether there is any validation error:

```
if($model->save())
{
     // redirect to view
}
else
{
    // check whether there are any errors
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($model->getErrors());
}
```